# Returning Rank with Full Text Search Contains Query

Tags: sql-server-2008, full-text-search

I have implemented Full Text Search on one of Sql Server 2008 Table.
Query works fine when search some words using contains.

I want to filter out the result on the basis of Rank functionality of Full Text Search. I am writing the following query

```
SELECT rank, * FROM Mas_text
 WHERE CONTAINS(text, 'Wanted and Engineers')
```

This query does not compile and give me error of  "Invalid column name 'RANK'"

Please suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **rank** function doesn't work with the CONTAINS query.  You'll have to use CONTAINSTABLE to get the rank.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879245.aspx).

Should look something like this:

```
SELECT Mas_text.*, k.rank
FROM Mas_text 
    INNER JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(Mas_text, text, 'Wanted and Engineers') k
    ON Mas_text.primarykey = k.[Key]
```